# Move mysql folder to another partition: symlink, fstab or mysql.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, mysql

I want to use a separate volume for my `mysql` folder. Now there are several options:

- creating a symlink
- mounting via fstab
- reconfiguring /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf and setting another data dir

Are there any advantages for one over the other. I'd prefer for the OS thinking that mysql folders are still the defaults as installed. So configuring a different data dir location is probably not the best option.

Would you rather go for symlink or `fstab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use fstab. In another case, do not forget about the apparmor rules

Comment: So in case I use fstab, no changes have to be made in apparmor, right? Could you maybe give an example for the correct fstab entry?

Comment: Does it matter if I use `ext4 default 0 2`, or just `none bind 0 0`? My drive is already mounted via fstab to the folder `/data`, so I would like to create a additional mountpoint for `/data/mysql /var/lib/mysql <properties>`

Comment: Yes, you are right.  

Example string in fstab:

    /dev/sdb1 /var/lib/mysql ext4 default 0 2

Comment: I mean, is there an important different using `ext4 defaults 0 0` instead of just `none bind 0 0`?

Comment: It depends on what you are mounting.
If you want to mount new partition - use variant  ext4 defaults 0 0
In another case (you mount folder from existing partition) - use none bind 0 0

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts on the three approaches:

1. symlink – this makes it easy for your fellow admins to see what's going on. (I seem to have misremembered update issues when the package manager sees a symlink where it expects a file or directory.)
2. fstab – this will have the smallest impact, in my opinion. Just remember it's a good idea to make the mountpoint, i.e. the empty `/var/lib/mysql` on the root partition, immutable with `chattr +i /var/lib/mysql`, so that things fail hard if for some reason the data volume is not mounted, instead of filling up your drive.
3. reconfiguring `my.cnf` – this will have minimal impact, unless you use tools that blindly assume things are in `/var/lib/mysql`. And there's always one more tool that you hadn't thought of, plus SELinux/Apparmor, plus logrotate, ….

None of these are "OMG, you will be doomed!", in my opinion. In some cases (multiple daemons on the same server), you'll need multiple `my.cnf`s anyway. Otherwise, I'd probably go with a mount or bind-mount.